# Glassfish3 server auto deployment

Tags: deployment, webserver, web-deployment, glassfish-3

I get a war file daily and deploy it on glass fish server via Remote Desktop connection (Windows server). I want make it do auto deployment e.g I just put war file on some predefined location and run script and that script deploy latest war and restart glass fish server as well.

So what should I do? Any batch script or any other script?

Answer (score 0):

- [You can put your WAR file in the auto deploy folder of GlassFish](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99b2/index.html):

  ```
  as-install/domains/domain1/autodeploy
  ```
- Or you can use a script to [deploy with the asadmin tool](http://blog.payara.fish/how-to-deploy-an-application-on-payara-server-or-glassfish)
- [Or you can use the REST interface to deploy](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2011/deploying-applications-to-glassfish-using-curl.html):

  ```
  curl -s -S \
      -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST \
      -H 'X-Requested-By: dummy' \
      -F id=@/path/to/application.war \
      -F force=true http://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application
  ```